# Re-partition (or re-install) root without console/"physical" access?

Tags: 16.04, server, partitioning, mount, encryption

I have a VPS where I have zero access to the virtual hardware. I cannot access the server console and I can't connect any install.iso to the virtual drive.

I had the VPS provider do the Ubuntu install, but I'd prefer to redo it myself - primarily to shove a layer of full disc encryption under the data.

I've read about `luksipc`, but it seem to require fiddling with the filesystems when they're offline. Which seem to be the limit no matter what way I try to take on the challenge.

I started thinking maybe I could create a new root in-memory and swap over to it, then be able to unmount `/` and do magic on the underlying filesystem.

I've not been successful yet.

This is what I've got thus far:

```
root@computer:~# cd /memroot/
root@computer:/memroot# ls
root@computer:/memroot# grep memro /etc/fstab
tmpfs               /memroot        tmpfs   rw              0       0
root@computer:/memroot# cat /proc/mounts | grep memroo
tmpfs /memroot tmpfs rw,relatime 0 0
root@computer:/memroot# debootstrap xenial . http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/
I: Retrieving InRelease
I: Checking Release signature
I: Valid Release signature (key id 790BC7277767219C42C86F933B4FE6ACC0B21F32)
I: Retrieving Packages
I: Validating Packages
I: Resolving dependencies of required packages...
I: Resolving dependencies of base packages...
I: Checking component main on http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu...
[...]
root@computer:/memroot# ls
bin  boot  dev  etc  home  lib  lib64  media  mnt  opt  proc  root  run  sbin  srv  sys  tmp  usr  var
```

Which I believe should be a workable filesystem. But switching to it alludes me:

```
root@computer:/memroot# switch_root /memroot /memroot/etc/init
switch_root: failed to mount moving /dev to /memroot/dev: Invalid argument
switch_root: forcing unmount of /dev
switch_root: failed to mount moving /proc to /memroot/proc: Invalid argument
switch_root: forcing unmount of /proc
switch_root: failed to mount moving /sys to /memroot/sys: Invalid argument
switch_root: forcing unmount of /sys
switch_root: failed to mount moving /run to /memroot/run: Invalid argument
switch_root: forcing unmount of /run
switch_root: failed to mount moving /memroot to /: Invalid argument
switch_root: failed. Sorry.
root@computer:/memroot# pivot_root . old-root
pivot_root: failed to change root from `.' to `old-root': No such file or directory
root@computer:/memroot# mkdir old-root
root@computer:/memroot# pivot_root . old-root
pivot_root: failed to change root from `.' to `old-root': Invalid argument
```

Am I chasing a pipe dream?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Never did get it work myself, but there are others who have:

https://github.com/marcan/takeover.sh

https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/226872/how-to-shrink-root-filesystem-without-booting-a-livecd/227318#227318

http://nullprogram.com/blog/2014/02/15/